# Jackson Databind - get properties not specified in pojo

Tags: java, jackson

I'm trying to figure out **how can I bind json to POJO**.

When `json` can sometime contain additional fields depending on various conditions. Basically speaking - some part of `json` will always contain same properties,

for example: name and age. But sometimes I'll get shoeSize and/or eyeColor. I cant make list of all possible properties that can be passed to me, because some of them are defined by user.

Is there possibility to achieve something like this?

```
class MyClass 
{
    public String name;
    public Integer age;
    public Map<String, String> additionalArguments;
    public MyClass(...) {...}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After going through documentation (again) I found annotation called `JsonAnySetter` and process reverting annotation `JsonAnyGetter`

```
class MyClass 
{
    public String name;
    public Integer age;
    public Map<String, String> additionalArguments = new HashMap<>();
    public MyClass(...) {...}

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String,Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
       return additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void putAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }
}
```